# MIME type for HTTP requests other than form submissions

Tags: http, post, http-headers, put, http-request

For requests not sent by HTML forms, does HTTP limit the Content-Type of a request to application/x-www-form-urlencoded for non-file uploads, or is that MIME type "right"/standard/semantically meaningful in any other way?

For example, PHP automatically parses the content into $_POST, which seems to indicate that x-www-form-urlencoded is expected by the server. On the other hand, I could use Ajax to send a JSON object in the HTTP request content and set the Content-Type to application/json. At least some server technologies (e.g. WSGI) would not try to parse that, and instead provide it in original form to the script.

What MIME type should I use in POST and PUT requests in a RESTful API to ensure compliance with all server implementations of HTTP? I'm disregarding such technologies as SOAP and JSON-RPC because they tunnel protocols through HTTP instead of using HTTP as intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer

*You should specify whichever content type best describes the HTTP message entity body.*

### Long Answer

> For example, PHP automatically parses the content into $_POST, which seems to indicate that x-www-form-urlencoded is expected by the server.

The server is not "expecting" `x-www-form-urlencoded`. PHP -- in an effort to make the lives of developers simpler -- will parse the form-encoded entity body into the `$_POST` superglobal if and only if `Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded` AND the entity body is actually a urlencoded key-value string. A similar process is followed for messages arriving with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` to generate the `$_FILES` array. While helpful, these superglobals are unfortunately named and they obfuscate what's really happening in terms of the actual HTTP transactions.

> What MIME type should I use in POST and PUT requests in a RESTful API
>   to ensure compliance with all server implementations of HTTP?

You should specify whichever content type best describes the HTTP message entity body. Always adhere to the official HTTP specification -- you can't go wrong if you do that. From [RFC 2616 Sec 7.2.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1) (emphasis added):

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
>   Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. **If and
>   only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
>   recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type** via inspection of its
>   content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
>   resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
>   treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

Any mainstream server technology will adhere to these rules. Thoughtful web applications will not trust your `Content-Type` header, because it may or may not be correct. The originator of the message is free to send a totally bogus value. Usually the `Content-Type` header is checked as a preliminary validation measure, but the content is further verified by parsing the actual data. For example, if you're PUTing JSON data to a REST service, the endpoint might first check to make sure that you've sent `Content-Type: application/json`, but then actually parse the entity body of your message to ensure it really is valid JSON.